# IntelliJ not showing private or public icon aka visibility icon for methods aka

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is not showing the padlock telling me whether or not a method is private or public. A course I am taking has it being shown but I do not see this padlock in my IntelliJ.

I already tried clicking settings and made sure Visibility Icons is checked, however this only shows whether or not a Project is public or private not methods.

FYI I am using a PC and the course video is using a Mac

[Picture of the courses IntelliJ showing the padlock visibility icon by the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ZH3.jpg)

[Picture of my IntelliJ not showing padlock visibility icon by method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItEwc.jpg)

[Proof that I do have "Show Visibility Icon" checked in my IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zqeK.jpg)

Comment: For those looking for the "Lock Icon", check [this issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/6351017704082): > You can add `ide.locked.icon.enabled=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE to revert the old behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration you have shown of *Show Visibility Icons* is for the left side panel (Project/packages, etc), not for the editor panel.

[image]

There's a bug open for 2019.2 version of IntelliJ for this feature: 
[Structure view no longer displays method/field visibility padlock icons](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215974).

On the other hand IntelliJ only suggests visible attributes/methods in the autocompletion feature, I mean visible in the context they are.

For example, in a class, all of its own attributes and methods will be suggested, because they belong to that class, but those private attributes, in the context of another class won't be suggested.

So it doesn't matter if they are private or public or protected, because if in the context they are visible, you can use them.